# Error when installing "hawq init cluster" on Docker, ,"internal_load_library","dfmgr.c",208

Tags: postgresql, hawq

I've been trying to install a hawq cluster via these instructions on the [github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq/tree/master/contrib/hawq-docker) page.

They mostly work fine, until I get up to the last command `hawq init cluster`. The last part of the error log is this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create HDFS filesystem
------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE FILESYSTEM HDFS
(
    gpfs_libfile = ""$libdir/gpfshdfs.so"",
    gpfs_connect = ""gpfs_hdfs_connect"",
    gpfs_disconnect = ""gpfs_hdfs_disconnect"",
    gpfs_open = ""gpfs_hdfs_openfile"",
    gpfs_close = ""gpfs_hdfs_closefile"",
    gpfs_seek = ""gpfs_hdfs_seek"",
    gpfs_tell = ""gpfs_hdfs_tell"",
    gpfs_read = ""gpfs_hdfs_read"",
    gpfs_write = ""gpfs_hdfs_write"",
    gpfs_flush = ""gpfs_hdfs_sync"",
    gpfs_delete = ""gpfs_hdfs_delete"",
    gpfs_chmod = ""gpfs_hdfs_chmod"",
    gpfs_mkdir = ""gpfs_hdfs_createdirectory"",
    gpfs_truncate = ""gpfs_hdfs_truncate"",
    gpfs_getpathinfo = ""gpfs_hdfs_getpathinfo"",
    gpfs_freefileinfo = ""gpfs_hdfs_freefileinfo""
);

",,"internal_load_library","dfmgr.c",208,
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/home/gpadmin/hawq-data-    directory/masterdd"
Master postgres initdb failed
20171208:13:39:48:000221 hawq_init:centos7-namenode:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master >postgres initdb failed
20171208:13:39:48:000221 hawq_init:centos7-namenode:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-   Master init failed, exit
```

Looking in dfmgr.c, the error seems to be about a missing file, the name of which it is supposed to output via `ereport()` but I can't see it going to stderr or anywhere else.

The `initdb` binary exists, as does `postgresql`, and AFAICT the environment variables are set correctly.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Look in your pg_log directory on the master to see what the error is.  You also mentioned postgresql is there.  Make sure that isn't listening on port 5432 or else there will be a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker to run HAWQ, make sure that sshd is running as root user. HAWQ init uses local ssh to do some verifications.

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

using `initdb -D [HAWQ DATA PATH] -d` to show all debug message out. More detail infor would give you some hints.

Depends on your description, I think you should check your `$GPHOME/lib/postgresql` directory if it contains "fixedwidth.so". If not, go to your HAWQ source code, contrib/formatter_fixedwidth subdirectory. 
execute `make;make install`.